# Deploying Struts 2 and Jersey in Glassfish

Tags: struts2, glassfish, jersey

I am attempting to deploy Jersey 1.13 and Struts 2 inside the same WAR file on Glassfish.

I am using a very old version of Glassfish and unfortunately am stuck on this version (Version = Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_02)

The Struts 2 configuration is as per the documentation. THe problem is the filter will intercept all urls and attempt to handle them via the Struts 2 configuration. My question is how do you deploy Jersey (or any servlet) inside the same war as a Struts 2 application?

Below is the web.xml file that I am using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.portal.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesConatiner.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.portal.web.actions.WLSessionFilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsp/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this as follows:

In web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.portal.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.portal.web.actions.WLSessionFilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In struts.xml I added this under the  element

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/api/.*" />
```

The URL is still sent to the struts framework first but is ignored due to the above excludePattern. This then allows my servlet mapping to handle the URL and pass it into the Jersey framework.

This approach does mean you have to prefix your Jersey URLs with api (or what ever you define) e.g.

`http://<domain-name>/api/resource/id`

This works until you add security into the mix. The problem comes from wanting to use FORM based authentication for Struts and Basic Authentication for Jersey. Unfortunately web.xml only allows you to define a single login-config for an application which meant I was stuck using either FORM based authentication or Basic Authentication for both Struts and Jersey.

Given this I decided to deploy the Jersey application in it's own WAR which means I didn't end up using the above solution in the end. The good news is that if you don't want to use different authentication methods (or any authentication) the above approach does work for deploying Jersey and Struts 2 in the same WAR.

Comment: +1 on finding a flexible approach that employs a feature of the framework.  Just as a note on the two wars (and you probably already ran across this), you could use OAuth (https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/OAuth) for securing the services and still have them in a single war.

Answer (score 3):

I have an application using Struts2 and Jersey, and the approach that I have used successfully is to map the Struts2 filter on the `struts.action.extension`:

web.xml:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

struts.xml:

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action" />
```

Alternatively, you could give your root Struts2 namespace a value like "/ui" and give your Jersey services a root path like "resources" and then map to those in your `web.xml` like this:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: :i am curious about this approach as this means we are struck with using `.action` as extension as in many cases people want no extension.I do not have any idea about Jersey so asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: Fair enough.  I will update the answer with another approach!

Comment: This approach works but forces you to have a ui prefix in all of your struts urls which was not an option given the url requirements I have to work with. See my answer below for an approach which allows you to not specify a prefix for your struts URLs. It does require a prefix for your REST URLs but this was a requirement for me so it wasn't a big deal.